# Facebook registration page - Invalid 'client_id' when not logged into Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have made a Facebook registration form that works with custom fields and functions as I expect, EXCEPT when the user is **not logged** into facebook when they first visit the form.

In this situation the form does not render on screen and the following error appears:

> Unable to load the registration form for this ID. You may have
>   previously blocked this app on Facebook. Go to your Facebook privacy
>   settings to unblock this app. (Error: Invalid 'client_id'.)

Now I know already that this has been discussed on the site but the solutions offered elsewhere don't work for me and I really want this to work based in the XFBML solution that facebook supports (a demo is here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/)

If you logout of facebook you can visit a test of my code, taken directly from the facebook example and hardly modified here: https://www.askanutritionist.com/fb.html

By the way, yes sandbox is disabled in the facebook app settings as thats a common fix others on S.O. have suggested.

Thanks for your time.
Note; I would have commented on other existing questions with this topic but stackoverflow won't let me (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm; I never actually fixed this properly.  Instead I made a work around and was able to do a javascript check via the facebook sdk to see if the user was logged in or not when they first hit the page that has the facebook registration form.

I do an http redirect if they aren't logged in (or aren't authorised) and if they are logged in later in the page I call to init the facebook form.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId      : xxxx, // App ID
    channelUrl : 'http:///xxxxx/fbchannel.php', 
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

// Additional initialization code here
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // all ok!
        //var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        //var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        window.location.href="create_account_with_facebook?authorizefirst";
    } else {
        window.location.href="create_account_with_facebook?loginfirst";
    }
});
};
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that the app whose ID you're using isn't restricted demographically (e.g. by age or country) and that it isn't still in sandbox mode.

If it is restricted or in sandbox mode, users who aren't logged in and who meet the restrictions applied (or for sandbox mode, are admins of the app) can't see the existence of the app or its details until they log in.