# Invalid App ID: clientID when running nodejs app with passport

Tags: node.js, facebook-oauth, passport.js, passport-facebook

Following [this tutorial](http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/02/23/authentication-using-passportjs/)

Which led me to [this repo](https://github.com/DanialK/PassportJS-Authentication) that I copied into my directory. Of course it did not run just like that so I had to run `npm install` on various times like:

`npm install mongoose`
`npm install passport-local`
`npm install passport-facebook`
etc. which then created new files all over the place, so I am wondering if any of those are now somehow interfering with the authentication. Because when I run the server locally I attempted to login through Facebook. Then I got the error

```
Invalid App ID: clientID
```

I thought all I needed to do was to add my credentials in there? but the files in the directory created by `passport-facebook` look like they need heavy modification.

[image: new files]

In my passport.js file I had made this modification

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: xxxxxxxxx, //my "App id" from Facebook
    clientSecret: xxxxxxxxx, //my "App Secret"
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/facebook/callback" //found this format on a tutorial
},
```

Here is my `routes.js`

```
var User = require('../app/models/user');
var Auth = require('./middlewares/authorization.js');

module.exports = function(app, passport){
    app.get("/", function(req, res){ 
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
          res.render("home", { user : req.user}); 
        }else{
            res.render("home", { user : null});
        }
    });

    app.get("/login", function(req, res){ 
        res.render("login");
    });

    app.post("/login" 
        ,passport.authenticate('local',{
            successRedirect : "/",
            failureRedirect : "/login",
        })
    );

    app.get("/signup", function (req, res) {
        res.render("signup");
    });

    app.post("/signup", Auth.userExist, function (req, res, next) {
        User.signup(req.body.email, req.body.password, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            req.login(user, function(err){
                if(err) return next(err);
                return res.redirect("profile");
            });
        });
    });

    app.get("/auth/facebook", passport.authenticate("facebook",{ scope : "email"}));

    app.get("/auth/facebook/callback", 
        passport.authenticate("facebook",{ failureRedirect: '/login'}),
        function(req,res){
            res.render("profile", {user : req.user});
        }
    );

    app.get("/profile", Auth.isAuthenticated , function(req, res){ 
        res.render("profile", { user : req.user});
    });

    app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/login');
    });
}
```

I had read in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926770/facebook-registration-page-invalid-client-id-when-not-logged-into-facebook) to take these precautions

"Check that the app whose ID you're using isn't restricted demographically (e.g. by age or country) and that it isn't still in sandbox mode."

Here is a screenshot, not sure what else I need to do here
[image: facebook dash]

Comment: Does you application has a route serving `auth/facebook/callback` and `example.com` is replaced by your domain?

Comment: @punund, `example.com` is replaced by my actual domain. And yes I do have a route called `auth/facebook/callback`. I updated the details.

Comment: Well, you should have it before trying to debug.